# Fragment onResume() and backStack issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragment-backstack

I am stuck with situation for resuming my fragment when I am coming back from another fragment.

Scenario :

I have a `Fragment A`. Now I am opening multiple fragment with in `Fragment A` say : `A1, A2, A3 ...` using a frame layout.

Now I am initiating a new Fragment say `Fragment B` from one of A1/A2/A3 ...

I am performing some action over `Fragment B` and now when I Pop Out my `Fragment B` then I am not able to get onResume() of `Fragment A`

Just need to get onResume() while I get back from `Fragment B`

Any help over this needed!

Highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: it's not clear how your fragments are organized. please provide some detail.

Answer (score 1):

Launch fragment A1, A2, A3 with childfragment manager from fragment A and launch fragment B with main fragment manager.

For Example :
To perform any fragment operation we have two fragment manager, If you are performing any fragment operation within a fragment you should use getChildFragmentManager() inplace of getSupportFragmentManager().

Now here, to launch fragment A1, A2 and A3 you should use getChildFragmentManager() and When launching fragment B you should use getSupportFragmentManager(). So when you press back from fragment B you will get onResume callback in fragment A.

Comment: Thanks AK Ali .. was performing some code stuff like this only .. Let me check it once. will update you.

Comment: Thanks AK Ali for your response. I recovered that problem using Interface. Will update you all with my solution. :)

Comment: Hey AndroidHacker, Im having the same issue, can you post the code you used to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you have added your fragment B, have you added the transaction to the backstack with this command: addToBackstack(null); by this way, you can restore the previous state when you press back on fragment B and return to fragment A.

Comment: Yes.. I am using addToBackstack(null); while initiating Fragment B but with no success ...