# On back pressed getItem of FragmentPagerAdapter is not called. While I have an Activity and three fragments in it

Tags: android

*My Activity which have three fragments in it*

```
    package com.appointment.activities;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.appointment.adapters.TabsPagerAdapter;
    import com.appointment.fragments.TabViewFragment;
    import com.example.activity.R;

    /**
     * Created by Akshay on 8/17/2015.
     */
    public class HomePageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static ActionBar actionBar;
    public static int fragment_count = 0;
    public static FragmentTransaction  fragmentTransaction;``
    ImageView menu_icon;
    Animation profile_in, profile_out;
    LinearLayout right_slider_layout;
    boolean menu_in = false;
    TabsPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_page_layout);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        View custom_action_bar =              LayoutInflater.from(actionBar.getThemedContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new     ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        profile_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_to_left_animation);
        profile_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_right_animation);
        right_slider_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.right_slider_layout);


        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setCustomView(custom_action_bar, layoutParams);
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#6FEAD1")));

        menu_icon = (ImageView)actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.menu_icon);
        menu_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!menu_in)
                {
                    right_slider_layout.startAnimation(profile_in);
                    right_slider_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    menu_in = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    right_slider_layout.startAnimation(profile_out);
                    right_slider_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    menu_in = false;
                }
            }
        });

        Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) custom_action_bar.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);

        Log.e("ACTION BAR", actionBar + "");
        TabViewFragment tabViewFragment = new TabViewFragment(actionBar);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, tabViewFragment).addToBackStack("TabViewFragment").commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "home onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
       /*else if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 2){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hahahah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            actionBar.removeAllTabs();
            TabViewFragment tabViewFragment = new TabViewFragment(actionBar);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, tabViewFragment).commit();
        }*/
        else
        {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
    }

}
```

*First Fragment with tabs and viewPager this is the fragment which is creating problem *

```
    package com.appointment.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.appointment.activities.HomePageActivity;
import com.appointment.adapters.TabsPagerAdapter;
import com.example.activity.R;
/**
 * Created by Akshay on 8/17/2015.
 */
public class TabViewFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Specialities", "Doctor" };

    public TabViewFragment(ActionBar actionBar)
    {
        this.actionBar = actionBar;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view_layout, container, false);
        HomePageActivity.fragment_count = 1;

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.removeAllTabs();
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        if(tab.getText().equals("Specialities"))
        {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
        else if(tab.getText().equals("Doctor"))

        {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }
}
```

*FragmentPagerAdapter to get view and show in viewPager*

```
    package com.appointment.adapters;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

import com.appointment.fragments.DoctorFragment;
import com.appointment.fragments.SpecialitiesFragment;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 8/17/2015.
 */
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                Log.e("GET ITEM", "getItem()");
                return new SpecialitiesFragment();
            case 1:
                return new DoctorFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

*Second fragment*

```
    package com.appointment.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.appointment.activities.HomePageActivity;
import com.appointment.adapters.DoctorListViewAdapter;
import com.example.activity.R;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 8/20/2015.
 */
public class DoctorListFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView doc_name;
    ListView doctor_listview;
    String doctor_name[] = {"Dr. Paul Wagner", "Dr. Robert", "Dr. Sam", "Dr. John", "Dr. Michel", "Dr. Paul", "Dr. Smith", "Dr. Tom", "Dr. Will", "Dr. Jerry"};
    String speciality[] = {"Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist", "Cardiologist"};
    String doctor_address[] = {"25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA", "25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA", "25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA", "25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA", "25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA", "25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA", "25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA", "25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA", "25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA", "25 Street Avenue, Newyork, USA"};
    int doctor_image_id[] = {R.drawable.docicon, R.drawable.docicon, R.drawable.docicon, R.drawable.docicon, R.drawable.docicon, R.drawable.docicon, R.drawable.docicon, R.drawable.docicon, R.drawable.docicon, R.drawable.docicon};
    Context context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity();
        HomePageActivity.actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        HomePageActivity.fragment_count = 2;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctor_list, null);
        doctor_listview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.doctor_listview);
        doctor_listview.setAdapter(new DoctorListViewAdapter(context, doctor_name, speciality, doctor_address, doctor_image_id));

        doctor_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                doc_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.doctor_name);
                DoctorDetailsFragment doctorDetailsFragment = new DoctorDetailsFragment(doc_name.getText()+"");
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, doctorDetailsFragment).addToBackStack("DoctorDetailsFragment").commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

*Third fragment*

```
    package com.appointment.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.appointment.activities.BookAppointmentActivity;
import com.appointment.activities.HomePageActivity;
import com.appointment.adapters.DoctorDetailsListViewAdapter;
import com.example.activity.R;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 8/20/2015.
 */
public class DoctorDetailsFragment extends Fragment{

    ListView doctor_detail_listview;
    TextView book_appointment, doc_name;
    Context context;
    int detail_icon[] = {R.drawable.address, R.drawable.speciality, R.drawable.education, R.drawable.achievement};
    String detail_title[] = {"ADDRESS", "SPECIALITY", "EDUCATION", "ACHIEVEMENTS"};
    String detail_description[] = {"FLAT #24, AVENUE APPT., AVENUE STREET, NY", "BROOKDALE UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL AND MEDICAL CENTER BROOKLYN HOSPITAL CENTER", "MBBS, MD, PHD, PHARMD", "DOCTOR OF SCIENCE, HONORARY DOCTORATE"};
    String doctor_name;

    DoctorDetailsFragment(String doctor_name)
    {
        this.doctor_name = doctor_name;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity();
        HomePageActivity.fragment_count = 3;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctor_info, null);
        doc_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.doc_name);
        book_appointment = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.book_appointment);
        doc_name.setText(doctor_name);
        doctor_detail_listview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.doctor_detail_listview);
        doctor_detail_listview.setAdapter(new DoctorDetailsListViewAdapter(context, detail_icon, detail_title, detail_description));
        book_appointment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent book_appointment_intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BookAppointmentActivity.class);
                book_appointment_intent.putExtra("DOCTOR_NAME", doctor_name);
                startActivity(book_appointment_intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }


}
```

*Speciality fragment*

```
    package com.appointment.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.appointment.activities.HomePageActivity;
import com.appointment.adapters.SpecialitiesGridAdapter;
import com.example.activity.R;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 8/17/2015.
 */
public class SpecialitiesFragment extends Fragment {

    GridView gridView;
    Context context;
    String specialities[] = {"General Physician", "Gynacologist", "Orthopendician", "Pediatrician", "Dentist", "Ophthalmologist", "Homeopath", "ENT Specialist", "Cardiologist", "Psychiatrist", "Ayurveda", "MF Specialist"};
    int iconID[] = {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.nine, R.drawable.ten, R.drawable.eleven, R.drawable.tweleve};
    //ActionBar actionBar;
    HomePageActivity  homePageActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.specialities_layout, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
        gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(new SpecialitiesGridAdapter(context, specialities, iconID));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView textView;
                DoctorListFragment doctorListFragment = new DoctorListFragment();
                textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(textView.getText().toString().equals("Cardiologist"))
                {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, doctorListFragment).addToBackStack("DoctorListFragment").commit();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

*Doctor Fragment*

```
    package com.appointment.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.activity.R;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 8/17/2015.
 */
public class DoctorFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctor_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: Please refer the same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584508/fragment-onresume-and-backstack-issue/31586648?noredirect=1